# asp.net mvc json 2 times post to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

```
function onTestComplete(content) {
    var url = '<%= Url.Action("JsonTest","Organization") %>';
    $.post(url, null, function(data) {
        alert(data["name"]);
        alert(data["ee"]);  
    });
}

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("JsonTest", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST",
     OnComplete = "onTestComplete" }))

{ %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("name") %><br />
    <input type="submit" />
<% } %>
```

controller:`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonTest() {
 var data = new {
  name = "TestName", ee = "aaa"
 };
 return Json(data);
}
```

Due to some reason When I click on the button (My Break point is in the controller jsontest method) **The jsontest is called twice**(that's the real problem).I want to call it once as usual,using Ajax.BeginForm( "", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",  OnComplete = "onTestComplete" })) **I am able to call it once but it doesn't post the values to the controller.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's being called twice because you're calling it twice - once by `Ajax.BeginForm` and once in `onTestComplete`.

The controller doesn't get any values because it doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: Get rid of the second call in `onTestComplete`.

Comment: passing null to the url in the post is stopping the displaying of alerts?

Comment: Why are you sending a second POST?